# How to optimize loading of a large XAP file

Tags: silverlight-5.0

We have inherited a silverlight application used in banks. This is a huge silverlight application with a single xap file of 6.5MB size.

Recently one the core banking applications has updated their services to delete the entire browser cache from the users machine on daily basis.

This impacts the silverlight application directly. We cannot afford to download the 6 MB file every day. On a long term basis I know we need to break this monolith in to smaller manageable pieces and load them dynamically.

I wanted to check if there are any short term alternatives.

1. Can we have the silverlight runtime load the xap in to different director ?
2. Will making the application Out of Browser application give us any additional flexibility in terms of where we are loading the xap from ?

Any other suggestions which can help us to give a short term solution will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What is inside your xap file ? (change extension to .zip and check what is inside)

Are you including images, sound inside your xap file ?

Are all dlls used necessary ?

Short-term alternatives are :

- do some cleanup of your application (remove unused dlls, images, code,...)
- rezip your xap file using a more powerful compression tool to save some place
- Also, some tools exists to "minify" the size of your xap file. (but I never tried them)

Here is a link that has helped me to reduce my xap size :

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/My-XAP-file-is-5-Mb-size-is-that-bad.aspx

**Edit to answer your comment :**

I would suggest using the Isolated Storage.

Quote from http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/My-XAP-file-is-5-Mb-size-is-that-bad.aspx :

Use Isolated Storage: keep in cache XAP files, DLL’s, resources and application data. This won't enhance the first load of the application, but in subsequent downloads you can check whether the resource is already available on the client local storage and avoid downloading it from the server. Three things to bear in mind: It’s up to you building a timestamp mechanism to invalidate the cached information, by default isolated storage is limited to 1 Mb size (by user request it can grow), and users can disable isolated storage on a given app. More info:Basics about Isolated Storage and Caching and sample.

Related links :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd434650.aspx

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/09/24/silverlight-isolated-storage-caching.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Yes I have checked inside the XAP files. It has the application assets and necessary assemblies. The third party assemblies are downloaded separately in the background. The main issue still is if I can load these xap to any other location apart of temporary internet files. Since the banks have very bad networks (less than 50 KBps effective download speed) downloading these files every day after cache clearing is unwanted traffic.